# Google Search Appliance index content from database

Tags: search, google-search-appliance

Instead using the google search appliance crawler for index content, im using a query to a sql server database.

The query is running fine, but i supposed that all these registries belong now to the Default collection (the complete index of Google Search Appliance).

Do you know how could i create a new Collection with only the data of the query?

Thanks in advance.
Best Regards.
Jose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi try adding the following:

Add the following to your **Crawl URLs Start Crawling from the Following URLs**

```
^googledb://
```

This will include all databases to be crawled.

Add the following to your Collections **Include Content Matching the Following Patterns**

```
^googledb://<database-hostname>/<DB_SOURCE_NAME>/
```

Comment: This will allow the GSA to index the content.  You'll need to create a collection and then use the above pattern to filter on content just from the DB.