# Google Search Appliance Database Feed

Tags: database, feed, google-search-appliance

I am setting up a GSA box for the first time for work. I have set up a connection with a database (for a people search) that successfully crawls all the rows. It then created a feed for me but always returns **"Failed in error"** with the following in the log:

```
ProcessNode: Does not match patterns, skipping record with URL: googledb://<host>/<Database>/azE9MTIsMQ
```

So I try adding the databases to the crawl list (i.e. from [Google Search Appliance index content from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2228281/google-search-appliance-index-content-from-database)). But that always returns

```
^googledb:// will not be included because it does not match any of the 'Follow and Crawl Only URLs' pattern
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out what to put into that section. What value do I need to include in the **Follow and Crawl Only URLs** field?

Comment: I have temporarily solved it by putting in the whole database path in both fields.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add that to the "Follow and Crawl Only URLs with the Following Patterns:" section.  That pattern will allow any database feed.